# Where & how is the 2nd group used in the KZG Commitment Scheme in case the 2 groups are not the same?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings, commitments

This is about the [KZG Polynomial Commitment Scheme](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2010/6477178/6477178.pdf)

In Section 2, it's written

> We use the notation $e : \mathbb G \times \mathbb G \mapsto \mathbb G_T$ to denote a symmetric (type 1) bilinear pairing.The choice of type 1 pairings was made to simplify presentation, however, our constructions can easily be modified to work with pairings of types 2 and 3 as well.

The above uses only one Elliptic Curve Group whose generator $\mathbb G$.

In the appendix where the document describes Bilinear Pairings, this is the description.

> For three cyclic groups $\mathbb G,\widehat{\mathbb G}$ and $\mathbb G_T$ (all of which we shall write multiplicatively) of the same prime order $p$, a bilinear pairing $e$ is a map $e : \mathbb G \times  \widehat{\mathbb G} \mapsto \mathbb G_T$

Note that here 2 different elliptic curve groups $\mathbb G$ & $\widehat{\mathbb G}$ respectively are used (instead of $\mathbb G$ being used as both the first & second group in the earlier description).

And this is not just for type 1 pairings, but all 3 types of pairings can have different generators.

I am a little confused about how the proof would work if the 2 generators were different.

For e.g. if we have to prove

$Q(x) = \frac {F(x) - c} {x-b}$,

This is how we do it.

$Q(x)(x-b) = F(x) -c$

Evaluating at $x=a$

$Q(a)(a-b) = F(a) - c$

Now we multiply both sides by $G$ (which is the generator of the group $\mathbb G$ & this becomes

$Q(a).G.(a-b) = F(a).G - c$

Now $C_Q = Q(a).G$ (commitment of $Q$) &

$C_F = F(a).G$ (commitment of $F$)

From here, it's easy to prove that if $e(Q(a)G, (a-b)G) \stackrel{?}{=} e((F(a)-c)G, G)$ is true, then the original statement $Q(x)(x-b) = F(x) -c$ is true. (This proof is also given in the KGZ paper in multiplicative notation). However, I am not able to derive the proof for $G_1 \ne G_2$ - how do I derive the proof for the above in case I am using two different groups with generators $G_1$ & $G_2$.

Now this easy converting of a polynomial into it's commitment by multiplying both sides by the single generator is key to using pairings to  prove without knowing the polynomial itself.

I am not sure how this translates to the two groups being different $\mathbb G$ & $\widehat{\mathbb G}$ because they would then have different generators & you won't be able to multiply both sides by the same generator to convert the polynomial into it's commitment so as to verify a proof without knowing the polynomial itself (and just knowing the SRS).

So where exactly is the generator of the 2nd Group $\widehat{\mathbb G}$
used & how does one convert the polynomials into their respective commitments in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pairings allow to do "multiplications in the exponent". Therefore, a good candidate for where $G_2$ comes in is where there's multiplication. The winner is $$Q(x)(x-b) = F(x) -c.$$
The polynomial equality required for verification can be computed by:
$$e(Q(a)G_1, (a-b)G_2) \stackrel{?}{=} e((F(a)-c)G_1, G_2).$$

**Correctness:** Assuming $$e(Q(a)G_1, (a-b)G_2) = e((F(a)-c)G_1, G_2),$$

then, by the bi-linearity of the pairing we have $$Q(a)*(a-b)e(G_1, G_2) = (F(a) - c)e(G_1, G_2).$$
Which holds if and only if $Q(a)(a-b) = F(a) - c$ (over the appropriate field) as desired.

This version of the KZG in the asymmetric paring setting requires that the setup algorithm produces $aG_2$ as well.

Comment: I can prove that if $e(Q(a)G, (a-b)G) \stackrel{?}{=} e((F(a)-c)G, G)$ is true, then the original statement $Q(x)(x-b) = F(x) -c$ is true - note that I am using $G_1 = G_2$ - this proof is given in the KGZ paper & it can be proven easily. However, I am not able to derive the proof for $G_1 \ne G_2$ - that's my question.

Comment: The proof is generally the same. We just need to use the bilinearity of the pairing. I'll develop this later.

Comment: But in the case where $G_1 = G_2 = G$, converting the polynomial into a commitment involves multiplying both sides of the equation to be proved with $G$ at $x = a$ which converts the polynomial into a commitment of the polynomial - i.e. if there is a $Q(x)$ on one side then $Q(a).G$ is the commitment of the Polynomial $Q$. How would you do this if $G_1 \ne G_2$?

Comment: As written in the answer any commitment is computed with $G_1$. In other words, polynomial evaluation at $a$ will use group elements from the first group. But that is a separate question than Correctness.

Comment: I understand that commitments will use $G_1$. My question is about proof of correctness. I am able to derive proof of correctness when $G_1 = G_2$. I am unable to derive the same when $G_1 \ne G_2$

Comment: If you apply the bilinearity of the pairing to both sides of the pairing equality equation what do you get?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thank you.